# Add event listener at the end of a contact form to track conversions (Google Tag Manager)

Tags: iframe, google-tag-manager, addeventlistener, contact-form

I hope you can help me solve a small problem. I want to advertise a post on Facebook which will lead to a website with an embedded contact form. I would like to add an event listener once the user reaches the end of the contact form, so that I can track the conversions (how many people completed the form). The problem is that the contact form was created with a CRM software and the code was embedded as an iframe on the website. The link doesn't change when the user hits the "Submit" button. I have contacted the CRM provider and they referred to the Google Tag Manager. Does anyone know how to add an event listener there? I have added a screenshot of the last part of the contact form. The event listener should occur when clicking on the "Anfrage abschicken" (Submit) button.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlzJV.png)

If anyone has any idea it would be highly appreciated!! Also, if you need any additional information, please let me know.
Thank you

I don't know enough about programming to solve this problem by myself

Answer (score 1):

When you work with an iframe (child window), Google Tag Manager doesn't work by default because it is only installed on the parent window.

However, some tools have developed their iframes in a way that they send events to the parent window. If it's the case for your CRM iframe you will receive events in the browser console after having executed this code:

```js
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
   console.log(event);
});
```

Then, when you interact with the iframe events should appear in the console.

If they do, you can then send a data Layer event and you got your iframe listener:

```js
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
   /* here you should filter only messages coming from 
iframe with an if statement on the event object you receive */
   dataLayer.push({
     event: "interaction" // this is an example
   });
});
```

If events do not appear you have two solutions:

- send data to the parents window yourself if you can edit the code in the iframe (use `postMessage()` method)
- insert another GTM container inside the iframe

Here is an article I wrote with Hubspot meetings iframe, the process is the same: [https://data-marketing-school.com/en/blog/track-hubspot-meetings-iframe-with-gtm/](https://data-marketing-school.com/en/blog/track-hubspot-meetings-iframe-with-gtm/?utm_source=stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

GTM has a built-in trigger for classical html submits. But that really only works on ancient forms that use the ancient submission method.

You can use it, then test in preview to see if it triggers by the form.

Otherwise - the best you could do is add a trigger to the submit button click with maybe some form validation code to see if it would have theoretically be submitted.